# Looking to replace min and max of ndarray in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following `ndarray` :

```
c_dist = [[0.         5.83095189]
 [2.23606798 3.60555128]
 [5.83095189 0.        ]
 [5.83095189 2.82842712]
 [4.12310563 2.23606798]]
```

and I would like for each sub-array to replace the min with 1 and the max with 0, in order to obtain the following :

```
[[1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

I used the following :

```
for i in range(len(c_dist)):
    max_of_row = c_dist[i].max()
    for elements_of_row in range(len(c_dist[i])):
        if c_dist[i][elements_of_row] == max_of_row:
            c_dist[i][elements_of_row] = 1
        else:
            c_dist[i][elements_of_row] = 0
```

but it is obviously not very elegant.
Is there an python way of doing the comparison array by array please ?

Comment: is the `cdist.shape = (n, 2)` always True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than 2 columns:

```
out = c_dist.copy()
np.put_along_axis(out, c_dist.argmax(0), 1)
np.put_along_axis(out, c_dist.argmin(0), 0)
```

Or if there are multiple `max` and `min` values per row:

```
out = np.where(c_dist == c_dist.max(0, keepdims = True), 1, c_dist)
out = np.where(c_dist == c_dist.min(0, keepdims = True), 0, out)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in one line:

```
c_dist = [[0. ,5.83095189], 
          [2.23606798 ,3.60555128], 
          [5.83095189 ,0.        ], 
          [5.83095189 ,2.82842712], 
          [4.12310563 ,2.23606798]]  

new_list = [[int(i<=j), int(i>j)] for i,j in c_dist]
```

The result will be:

```
In [6]: new_list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[6]: [[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: Your welcome. please check the gray button and turn it to green if it was helpful.

Comment: Hi @Mehrdad, actually my example should state that there are cases when i an have more than 2 column. ei: the number of column is not fixed.

Comment: @FrankyDoul In those cases... what the logic. can you add an example of what you are saing.